# Why do the printed unicode characters change?

Tags: unicode, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

The way the unicode symbol is displayed depends on whether I use the White Heavy Check Mark or the Negative Squared Cross Mark before it or not. If I do, the Warning Sign is coloured. If I put a space between the symbols, I get the mono-coloured text-like version.

Why does this behaviour exist and can I force the coloured symbol somehow?

I tried a couple of different REPLs, the behaviour was the same.

```
; No colour
(str (char 0x274e) " " (char 0x26A0))
; Coloured
(str (char 0x274e) "" (char 0x26A0))
```

[Clojure unicode display](https://storage.googleapis.com/replit/images/1558097628241_51c9ccd13669339a6976e3761276c357.pn).

I expect the symbol being displayed the same way regardless of which symbol comes before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this behaviour exist

A vendor thought it would be a neat idea to render emoji glyhps in colour. The idea caught on.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_versus_text_presentation

> can I force the coloured symbol somehow

U+FE0E VARIATION SELECTOR-15 and U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16

http://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/

Comment: `(str (char 0x26A0)(char 0xfe0f))` does exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is about characters (code points), not glyphs (see it as "image" of a character).

Fonts are free to (and should) merge nearby characters into a single glyphs. In printed Latin scripts this is not very common (but we could have it e.g. ff,fi, ffi), without considering the *combining codepoints* which, per definition, should combine with other characters, to get just one glyph,

Many other scripts require it. Starting to cursive Latin scripts, but most cursive scripts requires changes. E.g. Arabic has different glyphs of initial, final, middle or separated character (+ special combination, common to cursive scripts). Indian scripts have similar behaviours.

So the base of Unicode has already this behaviour, and modern good fonts should be able to do it.

It was not so late, that emojii uses such functionality, e.g. country letters/flags to other common cases.

Often the Unicode documentation tell you of such possibilities, and the special code points which could change behaviour, but then it is task of the font to fullfil the expected behaviour (and to find good glyphs).

So: character (as unicode code point) is not one to one to a design (glyphs).